# MVC Routes not working with integrated MVC Web forms solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, webforms

I am integrating an MVC project with my current Web Forms Application. I used Nuget to install MVC into the solution (based on some reading I did, which suggested doing this will add the binaries and configuration necessary). I then added a new MVC project into the solution and edited the Global.asax.vb file as following for MVC Routes:

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
' Code that runs on application startup
 MVC.RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
End Sub
```

I configure my RouteConfig to ignore aspx files

```
Public Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*aspx}")
    routes.MapRoute(
        name:="Default",
        url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    )
End Sub
```

My Web form routes work fine but my MVC one doesn't. How can I fix this?

Error:

```
  HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
  The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is     temporarily unavailable.
```

Controller:

```
 Public Class HomeController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

Function Index() As ActionResult
    Return View()
End Function

Function About() As ActionResult
    ViewData("Message") = "Your application description page."

    Return View()
End Function

Function Contact() As ActionResult
    ViewData("Message") = "Your contact page."

    Return View()
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: what type error do you get when call your mvc action?

Comment: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Do you create view for your actions?

Comment: Yes I have created the views for the actions